# How to get a list of Definition objects in apache tiles 3

Tags: apache-tiles, tiles-3

I'm working with a legacy application which currently uses apache tiles 2. I'm in the process of upgrading it to 3.0, but encountered a problem with some of our custom code.

The code in question attempts to get a list of Definition objects and to find the name of a particular definition based on the template url attribute.

In Tiles 2 this is done using **UrlDefinitionsFactory** which has **readDefinitions()** method. This seems to be missing in Tiles 3.

How can I access a list of loaded definitions at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll be looking at `DefinitionDAO.getDefinitions(locale)`

I guess you'd need to create one from scratch, via (or the same way as) your `basicTilesContainerFactory.createLocaleDefinitionDao()`